# Get the bounding box of a sheared and rotated rectangle

Tags: math, geometry, transformation, bounding-box

I can get the bounding box of sheared or rotated rectangle using this formula

```
shearedW = Abs(Tan(shearX) * Height) + Width
shearedH = Abs(Tan(shearY) * Width) + Height
rotatedW = Abs(Cos(angle) * Width) + Abs(Sin(angle) * Height)
rotatedH = Abs(Sin(angle) * Width) + Abs(Cos(angle) * Height)
```

But how to combine those? I just need to know the width and height. The transformation is done by shearing then rotating the shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just build affine matrix for combined transformation and apply it to vertices, then get differences for y- and x- coordinates.

Note that first pair of formulas is wrong - it gives additional width and heght. Full width:

```
shearedW =  Width + Abs(Tan(shearX) * Height)
```

Comment: Yes, this is not the most efficient algorithm in terms of number of operations for this specific case but it is simple and can easily be generalized to different shapes and transformations.

Comment: Well, that will work but i need to get the dimension before doing the transformation. Edited to include the corrected formula.

Comment: You consider some rotated parallelograms. Note that two shears by two axes are equivalent to some shear + scaling+ rotation, so it is worth to define allowed transformations and resulting figures clearly.